Why MOSFET heats up and blows up at 50 kHz boost converter?
I have made a boost converter with a PWM frequency of 50 kHz. Its purpose is to convert 60 V to 310 VDC. I am using the HCPL-3150 optocoupler gate driver and the 20N60 MOSFETs as shown in the image below. But every time I operate it at a 50% duty cycle it gives 150 VDC which is fine but then it starts taking more and more current with time and then the MOSFETs heats too much and shorts out. I am not able to understand why I am getting this behavior. Even the load is very low but still. I have changed the gate resistors to 100 Ω to reduce the spike on gate but still I am getting the same issue.
I haven't even got to the maximum required voltage and there is almost no load and still getting these issues. A sample design I am using is shown below:

I have used a heat sink as well but doesn't work up. Even the snubber was adjusted but it didn't help.
Kindly help me solve this issue because I had tried 20N60, 10N80, 40N60 40N1202 MOSFETs and IGBTs but none worked. I didnt used IGBTs later due to my high frequency choice. Kindly help me solve this issue.
I am generating this pwm wave with the STM32 and giving it to the gate driver HCLP-3150 which drives the MOSFET.
The practical circuit is shown below. (Ignore the resistor that turned black, it still works):


Troubleshooting switching converters without an oscilloscope is a bit like stabbing in the dark. But as a start, maybe begin gradually increasing the duty cycle from 0 % upwards instead of immediately jumping to 50%

Please show the full circuit including the gate driver and any regulators that power the gate driver. Also, what diode did you use and what actual load did you have and, did you measure it to make sure it was the right value? What's R2 and C1 for?

There's no current sense resistor or transducer?

A "controller" should also be used ... A PWM duty cycle 0 to 80% should be ok. If not,  startup current should be ~150 A !

Please post Vgs, Vds and Id oscollograms.

Have you monitored the power supply current with an oscilloscope? You are looking for core saturation issues (current quickly increases). The inductor in the picture looks like it is susceptible to saturation issues due to small amount of turns.

This green core isn’t suitable for energy accumulation. It’s more for noise canceling when used as common mode choke.
The current through coil probably rises
to extreme values so a huge current flows through mosfet.
Use a toroid with different core material or gapped core (ETD,..).

But I currently have this toroid core and have seen this in many converters.kindly suggest me improvement in these as designing another inductor would be difficult. But if that is the only solution I can work on inductor than

You can try -8 core material from Micrometals (yellow-red). https://www.micrometals.com/products/materials/pc/

Made with microcap v12
To show the behavior, I simulated this circuit.

This show that a "controller" should be used to limit the current into the MOSFET.
Otherwise, the MOSFET is burned at starting ... Peak current Id=140 A.
Here is the steady state of this circuit. Peak current = 2.25 A.


(Would ramping up duty cycle to 5/6 in, say, 99 ms work? Is that a controller already?)

But I am having a heat up after some times.. the MOSFET initially is working fine

@kam1212 Have you a "true" IRF740? Some come from Asia and are "fake" ... Remember that was written on the device.

@Antonio51 I have used FQP20N60 not the IRF740. Which one is better for switching converters? Can you give some suggestions

@Antonio51 can the inductor saturation be an issue? I have less turns but the core material is good enough to give me this inductance at 50-70kHz

Don't have FQP20N60 in database ... Sorry.

If the inductor saturates, then you can have misfunction ... What is the maximum current of this inductor without saturating?

it looks like the inductance of the coil is too small to limit the current at such an operating frequency. It is necessary either to increase the frequency of operation of the converter or to increase the inductance of the coil.
